# CORS: Rest API with ASP.NET 4.5.1 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a problem allowing cross site scripting for my application. GET requests work fine when i try to do a POST i get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49187/api/CampaignRegistration. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:49187/Authentication/UnAuthorized?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FCampaignRegistration', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

My preflight request returns 200 OK (without the authentication header) but my actual request returns 302 Not Found (which contains my authentication header).

My preflight request looks like this:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
```

and the response is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

And my request payload headers are:

```
{Cache-Control: "no-cache", Authorization: "Basic XXXXX"}
```

I have enabled CORS in my WebApiConfig.cs like this (i will change the origin: * when it actually works). I removed everything related to CORS in my web.config.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

My WebApi Controllers all extends a BasicApiController which includes a custom authenticate attribute which looks like this:

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Authorization"))
            {
                string authHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                string cred =
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length)));
                string[] parts = cred.Split(':');
                string userName = parts[0];
                string password = parts[1];

                if (userName == _configRepository.WebApiUsername && password == _configRepository.WebApiPassword)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My frontend was made using backbone.js but i really don't think the issue is on the front end side. I have tried changing the web.config to no avail, from what i gathered nothing is needed in it after enabling CORS like i did. I tried bypassing the authentication for OPTIONS methods since my application does not use OPTIONS (outside of preflight requests) but, as expected, that did nothing as the preflight request is ok even without the authentication header. If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was client side. The authorization parameter was in the payload not in the headers.... /facepalm.